# Reversed parts of a dictionary according to its values

Tags: python, dictionary, reverse

I'm new to Python and i'm trying different things with dictionaries. I have doubts about how to reverse the order of all previous items to a item whose value is greater than 10

```
Input: [1 : value1, 2 : value2, 3 : value3, 4 : value4], knowing that (value3 * 2) > 10
Output : [1 : value2, 2 : value1, 3 : value3, 4 : value4]
```

With real examples from a dictionary:

```
Input :  {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 2}

Output : {0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 2}
```

If there are several numbers I wanted each group of items to be reversed:

```
Input :  {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 6, 6: 1, 7: 2}

Output : {0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 6, 6: 1, 7: 2}
```

Comment: This is totally unclear. What you call 'map' are Python sets. What is your rule to get the output from your input? Also, sets are not ordered, and that seems to be incompatible with what you're trying to do, whatever it might be...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille You're right, I was putting set instead of map in the examples. I'm going to change them.

Comment: Ok in python we call them dictionaries, and they are of type dict. The term "map" is actually a built-in function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map --not sure what you are trying to do though.

Comment: It's unclear what your condition for swapping values is. Could you clarify?

Comment: This brings other questions... Are all the keys integers, starting from 0, with increments of 1? Are they in order? If this is the case, you should rather use a list.

Comment: The objective is to change the previous groups of values to another whose value by two is greater than 10.

Comment: It sounds like you want to swap the values of all pairs that come before a pair whose value*key is more than 10? So in the case of `{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 6}` you swap the values of every pair before `2:6` because `2*6>12`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Kexus Exactly, that's all I'm looking for. Well, actually the value is 10 not 12, but that's the idea

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Suppose they don't have to be whole and they can be of any kind. I put those up for example.

Comment: What defines the order, then? The order of insertion (dicts keep that since Python 3.7), or the key values? You have to be specific, and give an example that isn't equivocal.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille the values related of each key

Comment: So please update your question and your examples to make it clear.

Comment: @delolath78 I have updated my answer based on the additional details you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def swapper(d):
    keys = []
    values = []
    for p in d:
        if p*d[p] > 10:
            values.reverse() # reverse the order of values
            for k,v in zip(keys, values): # update values
                d[k] = v
            keys = [] # empty the keys and values lists
            values = []
        else: # keep track of the things we will need to swap
            keys.append(p)
            values.append(d[p])
    return d
```

Comment: Good solution, but it only changes every two positions. For example if you execute it with the dictionary {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 1, 5: 6, 6: 1, 7: 2}). the key 2 is not made the swap.

Comment: Yes, by this I mean always come a value that meets that condition every two positions.

Comment: @delolath78 Can you provide the output you want for `{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 1, 5: 6, 6: 1, 7: 2}`?

Comment: This solution: {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 6, 4: 1, 5: 6, 6: 1, 7: 2}

Comment: @delolath78 So then it sounds like what you really want is "for each sequence of adjacent pairs where `key*value <= 10`, rotate the values 1 position to the left"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212802/discussion-between-delolath78-and-kexus).

Comment: Not exactly, look at the value of position 0, it has moved to position 2. This is why I have always said the rotation. 
Don't get confused with the value of position 4, which is also a 1 but it hasn't been changed because only she is in that group (only that key, since 5 already fulfills the condition)

Comment: The last proposed solution works just as I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you get confused between set and list. In case of list, the solution will be:

```
def map_reverse_partial(A):
    start = 0
    for index, ele in enumerate(A):
        if 2 * ele >= 16:
            A[start:index + 1] = reversed(A[start:index + 1])
            start = index + 1
    return A
```

In case of map, the solution will be:

```
def map_reverse_partial(A):
    start = 0
    for index, ele in enumerate(A.values()):
        if 2 * ele > 10:
            if index > start + 1:
                for i in range(start, (start + index - 1)//2 + 1):
                    A[i], A[start + index - 1  - i] = A[start + index - 1  - i], A[i]
        start = index + 1
    return A
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the idea was to play with the actions of a dictionary (not a set, changed by my confusion).

Comment: I just add the solution for map case.